# How do I store user input (the utterance) from Amazon Lex?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying to store the user utterance from the Lex bot. I am currently using DynamoDB. I do not need to store the slot. I am using this information to build a transcript.

I tried using event['inputTranscript'] to access the user input, but I get an error message saying that the lambda is unhandled in my lex bot.

Please note that event = intent_request, for those of you familiar with AWS documentation. Also, this is a helper function in lambda. There is a response to Lex in another function (Not shown) which is called after

```
def write_dynamo(intent_request):
    t = datetime.datetime.now
    tString = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
    table = dynamodb.Table('<TABLENAME>')
    ID = intent_request['userId'] + tString
    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']

    response = table.put_item(
        Item = {
             'ID': ID,
             'user': intent_request['userId'],
             'time': tString,
             'input': intent_request['inputTranscript']
        })
return
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: In order to help you solve this, you'll need to share the Lambda code with us. You also mentioned several unrelated problems, so if you want help with those too, I suggest writing them as individual questions and share the relevant code in each. Be careful not to share access tokens or skill IDs, you can simply replace those with xxxxxxxxx. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: So, are you having a problem with `intent_request['inputTranscript']` or your dynamodb table? The error about being "unhandled"  is usually because you are not supplying a response to Lex. Every request should have a response, so you should prepare some response after you record the transcript into your db. @sid8491 is good with Lex in Python, maybe he can help.

Comment: there is indentation issue in your code.